# How to delay a JQUERY onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I've found some solutions online for this but couldn't make them work for me. Or maybe I was doing it wrong. I am completely newbie in JS, can you please help me to delay this function?

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){ var $ = jQuery;
var $container = $('.social_container');
$container.masonry({
      columnWidth:350, 
      gutterWidth: 355,
      itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to delay it? If you want to wait until something else loads, you should probably put it in the callback function when that finishes loading.

Comment: I am loading facebook embeds. Normally facebook embed takes time to load. That's why trying to delay. I am not sure about callback function. @Barmar

Comment: What API are you using to load the embeds. I'll bet it has a callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout() of javascript :-

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $ = jQuery;
        var $container = $('.social_container');
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 350,
            gutterWidth: 355,
            itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimer()`

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
    setTimer(function() {
        var $ = jQuery;
        var $container = $('.social_container');
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 350,
            gutterWidth: 355,
            itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

This will delay it for 1 second.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for me. I've tried it earlier. I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AsifurRahman You accepted another answer that's almost identical. The only difference is my delay is 1 second, his is 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be to wait for the plug-in to load and only then call your function.

```
var finished_rendering = function() {
  console.log("finished rendering plugins");
}

// In your onload handler
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', finished_rendering);
```